# How to publish java web project in tomcat

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat

To publish one java-web application in tomcat, I copy the project that named 'demo-mvc' to the tomcat's webapps folder.Then I visit "http://localhost:8080/demo-mvc/xx.jsp" in the chorme browser after starting tomcat but it prompts "The requested resource is not available".I tried editing the server.xml as follows

```
<Context docBase="D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\webapps\demo-mvc" path="/demo-mvc" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:website"/>
```

Finally it still does no effect.I am confused about where the problem is.

Comment: Did the app fail to start in Tomcat, i.e. did you get any stacktrace in the logs?

Comment: did you restarted server after the copy ?

Comment: I have restarted the server

Comment: are you able to get to sample web apps which comes with tomcat? have you also added auth to get to various pages within the default tomcat installation?

Answer (score 1):

Try to clean your project from Project clean option and make sure you are mapping all your resources

In your web.xml the code should be like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```